# (Android) RadioButton: resetting event if unselected?

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group, android-radiogroup

As practice, I'm making this very simply app that allows users to answer a few questions to decide if they prefer dogs or cats.  I use `dogCounter` and `catCounter` int variables to count how many answers are pro-dog or pro-cat.

I have one question that asks: Which animal is the cutest?

If they select "dogs", for instance, the app adds 1 to `dogCounter`.  But if they later decide to select "cats" instead, `dogCounter`'s value remains the same (which is 1).  I'm trying to make it so that if "dogs" is unselected after previously being selected, `dogCounter` will revert back to 0.

I'm not sure what to do after this:

```
public void setCutestQuestion3(RadioGroup radioGroup) {
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

            radioButtonCutest = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId);

            if (radioButtonCutest != null) {

                if (radioButtonCutest.getText().equals("Dogs")) {
                    dogCounter += 1;

                } else if (radioButtonCutest.getText().equals("Cats")) {
                    catCounter += 1;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Could someone please help?  I'm embarrassed to say that I've spent two days trying to figure this out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, for every question you two answers that determine if the user prefers cat or dog is thaht correct ? In that case, unselect dog also means select cat:

```
public void setCutestQuestion3(RadioGroup radioGroup) {
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

        radioButtonCutest = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId);

        if (radioButtonCutest != null) {

            if (radioButtonCutest.getText().equals("Dogs")) {
                dogCounter += 1;
                catCounter -= 1

            } else if (radioButtonCutest.getText().equals("Cats")) {
                catCounter += 1;
                dogCounter -= 1;
            }
        }
    }
});
}
```

Hope it helped

Comment: Such a simple solution.  I feel like such a simpleton.  Thank you so much.  This works!

Comment: I know that feel it already happened to me ;) have fun with your app